# Magento 2 Checkout Page, different price setup

Tags: magento2, price, currency

Currently I'm on a magento project and somehow, I can't understand the logic behind this last page.

The Currency that I've got is EURO, and in the /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/pt_PT.xml says that the numbers are grouped by "." and decimal cases by ",".

The screenshot below shows on the right side, how its supposed to be. However, the left side is on a completly different pattern and I can't seem to find where to make this change.

[image]

Comment: In euro currency the (,) comma is used as decimal separator, while the (.) dot (point) is used as the thousand value separator like if some where it is written 125,45 it means that is 125 euro and 45 cents & if it is written as 1.525 it means that is 1 thousand 5 hundred & 25 euros please [refer this](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=219595)

Comment: And magento is working in the similar way so why do you want to change it?

Comment: Thing is, I changed the grouping so that the dot represented the thousands and the comma represents the decimals. However, this was only applied in certain areas of the website, so the solution that I made was formatting the price whenever I found it to be incorrect. This is the last place that the standard on the left is incorrect and I have no idea where to change it to be in order with what is at the right

Comment: @abr You shouldn't have to customize the format like you have though. Magento will format the numbers in the way you are attempting based on the locale & currency you set in your store. What locale do you have set in your store? It should be one that formats this way.

Comment: I've removed the changes in the zend data xml and my locale is set to Portugal on the backoffice. However, the issue maintains (incorrect number format all along the website)